# Android: Keyboard does not always appear on edittext focus

Tags: android, ios

I have a Login view. When the user starts the app, if he already synced with the server before, the app opens on the login view and the user is prompted to enter his login. In this situation, the keyboard opens automatically when the app starts. If, however, the user never synced before, the user is redirected to the configuration view and will sync from there. After the sync is over, the configuration activity finishes and the user then sees the login view for the first time. At this moment, the focus is on the PIN edit text, as it should, but the keyboard does not open.

I tried several solutions found online, none of which worked. This is my code in its current state:

View:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        EditText pinEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        boolean dbContainsUsers = controller.Dispatcher.Count(new controller.User(), false) > 0;

        if (!dbContainsUsers) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Configuration.class);

            startActivity(i);
        }

        pinEditText.clearFocus();
        pinEditText.requestFocus();
        imm.showSoftInput(pinEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="view.Login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/lgnEditTextMarginLeft"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeL"
            android:ems="8"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSynchroniser"
                style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btn_marge_top"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_sync"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeM"
                android:text="@string/btn_synchroniser" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnConfiguration"
                style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btn_marge_top"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_configuration"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeM"
                android:text="@string/btn_configuration" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.aaa.bbb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/RexforetTheme">
        <activity android:name="view.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="view.MenuPrincipal" />
        <activity android:name="view.Configuration" />

        <service
            android:name="service.WebDBService"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" in this place replace

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

in your menifest file

Answer (score 0):

you have android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" in this place replace

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in your manifest file.

Comment: This isn't working, but I'd like to ask: What was the reasoning behind trying this?

Comment: The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.